# Solve non-linear system of equations R

Tags: r

I try to solve a set of non-linear systems of equation using the nleqslv function in R. Unfortunately I run into troubles guessing the right initial values to make the function run sucessfully. I have a vector with values between 0 and 1, which are called c(t). They should satisfy the following equation

```
c(t)=A*(exp(-mt)+exp(-m(1024-t)))+B^2
```

Using three subsequent values of t I aim to determine the coefficients A,B,m using the following code

```
library(nleqslv)

C10 <- c(1.000000e+00,9.754920e-01,9.547681e-01,9.359057e-01,9.182586e-01,9.014674e-01)
system_size <- 1024

for(i in 2:5)
{
  C <- c(C10[i-1],C10[i],C10[i+1],i-2)
  #function
  target <- function(Coeffs){
  y <- numeric(3)
  y[1] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]-1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]-1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[1]
  y[2] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[2]
  y[3] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]+1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]+1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[3]
  y
 }
 init <- c(0.001,0.01,0)
 sol <- nleqslv(init, target,control=list(btol=.01), method="Broyden")
 }
```

The used initial values reflect what I get when plotting the associated values c(t). Nonetheless the generated output sol gives

```
chr "Jacobian is ill-conditioned (1/condition=9.0e-18) (see allowSingular option)"
```

Any idea what is going wrong and how to solve this?

---

OP edit: Modified Code to have minimal working example: added first few values for C10, adjusted loop and added value for system_size

Comment: A singular Jacobian indicates that the initial guess causes the solution to diverge. Nonlinear solvers are only as effective as the initial guess they start with, so changing your starting guess may help.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Provide values for `C10` and `system_size`. And check carefully if you haven't made any errors in the equations of your function.

Comment: @Bhas Added the requested values in order to have a reproducible example.

Comment: @Mislav Is it also possible to have the algorithm fail, although the inital guess is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your addition of some data for `C10` the example runs perfectly ok if one takes into account that the loop should take account of `length(C10)`.
Like this (with some changes; for why see below):

```
library(nleqslv)

C10 <- c(1.000000e+00,9.754920e-01,9.547681e-01,9.359057e-01,9.182586e-01,9.014674e-01)
system_size <- 1024

target <- function(Coeffs){
    y <- numeric(3)
    y[1] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]-1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]-1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[1]
    y[2] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[2]
    y[3] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]+1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]+1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[3]
    y
}

init <- 50*c(0.001,0.01,0)

for(i in 2:min(length(C10)-1,(system_size/2)))
{

    C <- c(C10[i-1],C10[i],C10[i+1],i-2)
  #function
    target <- function(Coeffs){
        y <- numeric(3)
        y[1] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]-1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]-1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[1]
        y[2] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[2]
        y[3] <- Coeffs[1]*(exp(-Coeffs[2]*(C[4]+1))+exp(-Coeffs[2]*(system_size-(C[4]+1))))+Coeffs[3]^2-C[3]
        y
    }

    cat("i=",i,"init=",init, "target(init)=",target(init),"\n")
    sol <- nleqslv(init, target,control=list(btol=.01), method="Broyden")
    print(sol)
}
```

With your initial starting values the model doesn't solve and gives the error message you mention. I have changed the value of `init` by increasing the value. And then a solution is found up-to `i=5`. Larger values with the given `C10` won't run since within the loop `C10[i+1]` is referenced (and it doesn't exist).

I have inserted a `cat` statement before the call of `nleqslv` and a `print(sol)` after the function call so that one can at least see what's going on and if a solution is actually found.

You do not need to specify `method="Broyden"` since it is the default.

You should test `sol$termcd` in the `for` loop end exit if an error occurs.

With scripts like this always print stuff inside the loop!

Mislav was correct: starting values can be totally wrong.

Even if starting values are ok the algorithms used can fail. That's why the package provides function `testnslv` and `searchZeros`.

I did some experiments (not shown here) with `testnslv` and the conclusion is that `method="Newton"`  is a failure. The dogleg global strategies always seem to work. The linesearch strategies don't always work.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right, it seems that I simply missed the fact that although changing the initial values there might be a problem later in the loop and since in my old setup did not show me the proceedings in the loop I came to the wrong conclusion that it does not work at all. Unfortunately with the current initial values I do not get to far (it is stuck at position 10). Is there any nice (automatic) way to guess the initial value? I only came to the brute force solution to simply reinitialize the algorithm with initial values in a certain range until succeeding..

Comment: I can't think of nice and easy way to guess/set initial values. If you can provide bounds for the initial values you could try function `searchZeros` in the package. Generate  for example 100 initial values for each parameter with a random number generator (e.g. `runif`) and don't forget to set the seed before running the generator (see `set.seed`) for reproducibility.

Comment: You could try to use the solution of iteration `i` as initial guess for the next iteration `i+1`. After the `sol <- nleqslv....`) do `init <- sol$x` **after** testing that there is a valid solution using `sol$termcd`.

Comment: Thank you, your idea got me much further. Sadly at some point I still get "Jacobian is too ill-conditioned (1/condition=1.0e-12)"-Warnings. Is there any way to "protect" the Jacobian?
Further I'm a bit anxious about the Message "No better point found (algorithm has stalled)", which I get sometimes. Am I going right that under the assumption of smoothly varying parameters there should not be any problem?

Comment: Have you read the `nleqslv` manual? There is an `allowSingular` item in the `control` argument. `No better point found ...` is documented in the manual. It means that no acceptable point has been found; in summary it means  that the function criterion is not lower than that  of the previous iteration. If the algorithm accepted the x values it would report  convergence even though function values are **not** acceptable. You will have to look at the resulting function values to decide if you can accept the output. You are warned!!!

Comment: I do not understand your last remark about smoothly varying parameters..

Comment: Why do your parameters `A, B, m` have to reproduce the values of `c(t)` exactly? Why not assume fixed values for`A, B, m` and use an optimization function to approximate `c(t)`? And then look at the residuals.

Comment: Yes, I did read the manual. I meant that by starting from previous values, this error could simply imply that the change from the previous iteration is to small to be coped by the algorithm. However when looking at the resulting values there clearly is something going wrong. The problem is that I am given the values for c(t) from measurements at different values of t and this seem to be the only way to extract the parameter values..

Comment: I do not agree with your last statement. It is not the only way to extract the parameter values. By trying to minimize e.g. a sum of squares of residuals (==> actual - predicted values) for the three parameters you can at least get values. Then by inspecting residuals you could possibly find out the cause of the trouble. Also your remark about starting from previous values being too small is not true.  Without a full dataset nobody can help you any further. Your issue could also be caused by your function and weird values for `c`.